theme.css is taking time to load in Primefaces saga
I am using primefaces 12 and the theme is default theme saga. theme.css file is taking alot of time to load, it is the heaviest file in the website. it is taking 1.29, 1.45 and sometimes even more time to load. is there a way to make it fast?
Tried on different machines, and tried on different browsers.

Does this answer your question? JSF2 Static Resource Management -- Combined, Compressed

@JasperdeVries it should already be minified by the SASS compiler in the theme as Saga comes compressed.  Its the same discussion being had here: https://github.com/orgs/primefaces/discussions/1779

Minified yes, but not gzipped or combined.
